# Como corto (desde la consola o el mismo canvas) un while lopp the python turtle graphics?

Tags: python, python-turtle

Estoy recreando un mini programa que da la posición de la estación espacial internacional, con turtle graphics. El problema es que no encuentro una manera de poder cortar el loop UNICAMENTE al escribir 'quit' en la consola.

Intente poner un input luego del 'time.sleep(5)', pero no me sirvió. También intente con screen.exitonclick(), pero lo unico que hace es cortar ya la iteración de una (como si estuviese esperando a que haga click para seguir).

Muchas gracias!

Les dejo aqui el codigo:

```py
import json
import turtle
import urllib.request
import time
import webbrowser
import geocoder


url = ' http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
result = json.loads(response.read())
file = open('iss.text', 'w')
file.write('There are currently' + str(result['number'])+' asses:\n\n' )

people = result['people']
    
for p1 in people:
    file.write(p1['name'] + '- on board' + '\n')
    
g1 = geocoder.ip('me')
file.write('\n your current lat/ long is:' + str(g1.latlng))
file.close()
webbrowser.open('iss.text')
    
screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.setup(1280, 720)
screen.setworldcoordinates(-180,-90,180,90)


screen.bgpic('map.gif')
screen.register_shape('iss.gif')


iss = turtle.Turtle()
iss.shape('iss.gif')
iss.setheading(45)
iss.penup()


while True:
    url = ' http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json'
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    result = json.loads(response.read())
    
    location = result['iss_position']
    lat = location['latitude']
    lon =  location['longitude']
    
    lat = float(lat)
    lon = float(lon)
    print('\nLatitude: ' + str(lat))
    print('\nLongitude: ' + str(lon))
    
    iss.goto(lon, lat)

    time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

La instrucción `break` te permite salir del ciclo. La sugerencia es que valides alguna condición para ejecutarla (pues el while true indica que quieres correr ese ciclo hasta que algo pase, no?)

```
...
while True:
    url = ' http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json'
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    result = json.loads(response.read())
    
    location = result['iss_position']
    lat = location['latitude']
    lon =  location['longitude']
    
    lat = float(lat)
    lon = float(lon)
    print('\nLatitude: ' + str(lat))
    print('\nLongitude: ' + str(lon))
    
    iss.goto(lon, lat)

    if alguna_cosa < alguna_otra_cosa:
        break

(...acá irían otras cosas por fuera del while, si lo necesitas)
```

Es curioso porque ese caso **literalmente** está en la [página inicial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html) de la documentación de python turtle

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]